# du -sh keeps timing out!

Tags: directory, command-line-interface

i need to get the entire size of /storage, but using du -sh times out after about an hour! is there another way to get the entire directory size?

Answer (score 2):

Is `/storage` mounted as a separate filesystem? If so, you can simply type `df /storage` and that *should* work.

The fact that the command is timing out suggests that it's a network filesystem. If so, what filesystem type is it? What's it provided by and how are you mounting it?

Comment: you were right htank you, df worked!

Comment: how can i make it display in human readable format like MB and GB?

Comment: and i dont know how to tell the filesystem type, how do i do that?

Comment: `df -h` should make it human-readable. `df -T` will tell you the filesystem type. You can combine the two: `df -hT`. And `man df` will tell you more options.

Comment: okay awesome, looks like 135GB of images and ext3 file system.

Comment: how do i mount another harddrive to /storage on my new server?

Comment: @Andrew Fashion, one question per **Question** please.

Comment: @Andrew Fashion -- A lot of this basic stuff may be better suited for the http://unix.stackexchange.com/ site.