# rsync is just hanging, building file list

Tags: rsync

```
[root@centos /]# rsync -av --exclude thumbs /storage root@xx.27.1.xx:/storage
root@xx.27.1.xx's password: 
building file list ...
```

I've been sitting for about an hour... it's 135GB of images and folders

`/storage` is a mounted ext3 scsi drive.

Is it normal for rsync to be sitting this long calculating the files/directories?

Comment: How many files? With very large numbers of files it's gonna take a while.

Comment: probably thousands... images directory of user uploads...

Comment: I have seen this portion of rsync take well over an hour when there's thousands and thousands and thousands of files. If you run 'top' are you seeing I/O wait?

Comment: Just because I am curious, can you run `df -i` and tell us what you have for `IUsed` on /storage?  It will give us a rough idea of how many files+folders you have.

Comment: 1383641, is that the amount of files?

Comment: It is the number of inodes. There is one inode for every filesystem object like files and directories.  So no, it isn't the number of files, but it does tell us that you have a pretty large set of files.

Answer (score 28):

rsync 2.x does build a full file list up front.

Add the `-P` option and you'll see a progress indicator.

If you think it really is hanging, in another terminal find the pid of rsync and then

1. Run `strace -p PID` and see what it's doing.  (Hit ^C to stop.)
2. Run `ps -o wchan PID` to see where it is in the kernel.

Comment: Wow `strace` is cool! You'll probably find that something circular is going on: Like a link that refers to one of its ancestor directories. In my case I was using a virtual filesystem that had no limit on its depth, i.e. it had "infinitely" many subdirectories `tagfs/books/+/books/+/books/+/ ...`

Comment: @Zaz I also have a huge amount of subdirectories, in depth. But this is in my system design. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: @user1641443: I'm sorry, that's beyond me.

Comment: @user1641443: 1: [Try rsync>3.0 as Martin says](http://serverfault.com/a/208588/44697). 2: Run multiple rsync processes each on a on smaller sub-tree.  3: Open your own separate question.

Answer (score 16):

You should upgrade to **rsync 3.0.x** where you will get the benefit of incremental file lists, [explained here](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/FAQ.html#4). I am rsyncing millions of images (~200GB total) and saw an enormous speedup when going from rsync 2.x to 3.x.

Even so, it will probably take a long time to go through all that data. In my case it still takes over an hour between two pretty powerful DL380 G5 servers.

Comment: Also note that certain flags will force the old behavior; for me, it was `--delay-updates`.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov The only options I'm using are "-a" and "--progress" and version 3.1.x is *still* building an incremental file list.  Why?

Answer (score 3):

You noted [earlier](https://serverfault.com/questions/208467/du-sh-keeps-timing-out) that `du` was hanging as well. Something is up with this filesystem, and `rsync` is hitting whatever `du` was.

One quick thing you can check is for kernel error messages indicating a disk problem. Type `dmesg` and see what's at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this and your other question of `du /storage` hanging makes me think that neither `du` or `rsync` is the problem but rather there are some issues with `/storage`.

Answer (score 1):

The hang after the message "building file list..." can be caused by MTU mismatch, e.g. if you've set up the network interfaces with MTU 9000 but not the switch in between, small packets (like connecting to the rsync server) will pass through but not bigger ones (like sending the file list).

Comment: after much searching I came across this and it prompted me to go and check - was running rsync over a vpn with standard 1450 mtu but I am not in control of the equipment in between the sites - changed the vpn mtu down to 1430 and viola the rsync works 100% (and suddenly other network strangeness disappeared too!) thanks!